# Scalability in java

Tags: java

If millions of words are added in a Hash Set, on average, roughly, will there be any performance issues?
According to my opinion, since Hash Set has best case complexity of O(1), so on average it will be lower than O(log N) resulting no performance issues. I would still like answers by others. This is one of the question asked to me in an interview.

Comment: I get the feeling there is more to this question that what is presented. Why would an operation less than O(log N) not have performance issues?

Comment: As a rough estimation, it is hard to get performance issues. This is my view.

Comment: I'm just saying that when you talk about 'performance issues', it's usually a relative analysis. There might be better performance inserting into a Hash Set over some other data structures, but if you had, say, a stack, inserting should always be O(1), thus it will perform better than a HashSet on average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hashset provides good add performance. It should work fine. It should be also important to write hashcode() function correctly.

[image]